# Only collect logs with specific field by fluent-bit

Tags: fluentd, fluent-bit

For example, my logs look like:

```
{
 "fieldA":"logA",
 "foo":"bar"
}
```

or

```
{
 "fieldA":"logA",
 "fieldB":"logB"
}
```

In my case, I only want logs with field "foo" to be collected, while dropping other logs.

Comment: Take a look at `grep` filter plugin: https://docs.fluentd.org/filter/grep.

Comment: If you are looking to filter more complex JSON entries with nested pairs, you might want to take a look at https://github.com/iamAzeem/fluent-plugin-json. It uses JSON pointer syntax. See example: https://github.com/iamAzeem/fluent-plugin-json#example.

Comment: fluent-bit grep: https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/pipeline/filters/grep

Answer (score 0):

Use `grep` filter plugin to only include events with `foo` field:

```
[FILTER]
    Name   grep
    Match  *
    Regex  foo .*
```